# The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D025)

Tags: 2013, cme, event-system

I am using SDL Tridion 2013 SP1. I am getting this error from the Event System. This custom Event System is capturing all CME activity and storing it into a separate SQL database for logging purposes.

I am getting this error while doing any activity in CME:

> The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D025)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this really a Tridion question? The problems are with your own database aren't they?

Answer (score 7):

This issue is probably related with the MSDTC settings.

Verify that **Distribute Transaction Coordinator** Service is running on the server

- Go to **Administrative Tools > Services**
- Turn on the "Distribute Transaction Coordinator" Service if it is not running

If it is running then:

- Go to **Administrative Tools > Component Services**
- On the left navigation tree, go to **Component Services > Computers > My Computer** (you may need to double click and wait as some nodes need time to expand)
- Right click on **My Computer** & choose **Properties**
- Select "MSDTC" tab
- Ensure All MSDTC settings are as per the SDL Tridion Installation document
- If all these settings as per the expectation then follow the below procedure (Please do not ask for the logic, but this is how I was able to get rid of similar error):

  - Uninstall MSDTC
  - Reboot Your Server
  - Re-Install MSDTC and do configuration as per the SDL Tridion Installation document
  - Reboot Your Server
  - Hopefully it should be working now

Comment: And if you happen to be using a database that does not support distributed transactions - like SQL azure - make sure your code does not use transactions...

Comment: Not sure why somebody has down voted the answer, if some thing is wrong there, feel free to share and it will help the community

Answer (score 1):

Addition on the first answer. Do not only check the MSDTC settings on the Tridion CMS server but also on the CMS MAIL database server (SQL server) and if you are using an Oracle database for the CMS, check if XA transactions is installed.