# Why Does Publishing Gets Stuck On "Deploying" When Legacy Pack Is Installed?

Tags: publishing, 2013-sp1, upgrade, legacy-pack

I'm working on upgrading our Tridion 2011 SP1 installation to 2013 SP1. When I did my initial test performing the upgrade I did not install the Legacy Pack (as I was pretty certain we hadn't implemented any legacy templates).

When I got to the stage of testing publishing, I was receiving "Success" in the Publishing Queue. However, when I navigated to a folder with my Dynamic Component Templates I received the error regarding "Unable to get template type with legacy id."

So, I then installed the Legacy Pack. However, after that I began to have publishing problems - the item seems to successfully publish (it is updated on the server), but the Publishing Queue is stuck on "Deploying".

Checking the logs on both ends of the deployer don't show any problems. The publisher has entries like "DestinationController - All Deployer endpoints have completed, setting transaction to completed" with the correct transaction ID. Similarly, the HTTP Upload website's log has a en entry "TransactionManager - Finished handling of Deployment package" along with clean-up references.

**If I uninstall the Legacy Pack - Publishing finishes properly with "Success." Reinstall and it gets stuck on "Deploying"...**

My intention is to actually remove the dependencies on the Legacy Pack, but I was hoping someone could enlighten me as to why publishing gets hung up when the Legacy Pack is installed.

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**:
I enabled the Publisher's log file (Tridion MMC snap-in: Publisher settings > Activate logging) and the last couple entries are:

```
9/26/2014 4:47:12 PM <2808> Receiving deployment feedback for publish transaction [tcm:0-190440-66560] with status: Success
9/26/2014 4:47:12 PM <2808> The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D025)
```

So it looks like it receives the feedback of success, but then complains about "partner transaction manager". According to [another article](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4001/the-partner-transaction-manager-has-disabled-its-support-for-remote-network-tran) this is a DTC issue, however my settings seem to be correct in Component Services and again - *when Legacy Pack isn't installed publishing works fine*.

Comment: Can you clarify "when I navigated to a folder with my Dynamic Component Templates"?  Do you mean the actual folder in Tridion CME and the GUI showed an error? After installing the legacy pack, did this error go away?

Comment: @NickoliRoussakov - That's correct. In the folder in the CME that we place our Dynamic Component Templates, if I don't have the Legacy Pack installed, I get the "Unable to get template type" error. With the Legacy Pack installed, that error goes away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be DTC-related - the Publisher log indicated as much. However, my DTC settings were correct on the CM server and I even tried the linked solution I referenced in my question of uninstalling/reinstalling.

When looking at the log, it seemed like the error was actually occurring at the point the CM should be updating the Database with the new status that was just returned from the deployer target. Since it was a DTC error I went and looked at the SQL Server's DTC settings. It did not have Network DTC Access enabled. I didn't think it would be something on the CM DB server itself (since this doesn't change if I install the Legacy Pack or not), but on a whim, I enabled it and set to Allow Inbound & Outbound, and the other settings like the CM server. **After enabling DTC (which restarts MSDTC) publish transactions are completing with "Success".**

Looking at the 2011 SP1 environment I'm replacing I see that the CM DB does have DTC enabled as well.

I still don't know why having the Legacy Pack installed seems to change the behavior of how the CM communicates with the DB. I'm guessing it has something to do with the LegacyEventAdapter that's in play...